# Comparing data in database in PHP

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is saving some data in the database and when user will press "SAVE" button script will compare the data entered by the user with data already present in the database. If the data matches it will show a warning that is "The entered data is already in the database please use search bar to search it." In my case I only want it to check phone number and cnic (cnic = national identity card number). Here is what I am doing.

```
 <?php include_once("config.php"); // mysql_connect and database selection are in this file.
    $name = $_POST['name']; // data coming from save_info.php
    $gender = $_POST['option']; // data coming from save_info.php
    $cnic = $_POST['cnic']; // data coming from save_info.php
    $number = $_POST['number']; // data coming from save_info.php
    $address = $_POST['address']; // data coming from save_info.php
    $info = $_POST['info']; // data coming from save_info.php
    $check = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE num = $number AND cnic = $cnic"; // checking data
    $cresult = mysql_query($check);
    if (mysql_num_rows($cresult)==1) {
         echo "The entered phone number/cnic is already in the database, Please use search bar to search it.";
        header('refresh:10;url=save_info.php');
        }
        else
        {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO info(name, gender, cnic, num, address, info)VALUES('$name', '$gender', '$cnic', '$number', '$address', '$info')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close();
    header('Location:saved_info.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: and what is your problem you are facing ?

Comment: Its not working i mean i tried entering the phone number which is already in the database but its not showing any warning it simply saves the data.

Comment: this query will work if both phone number and nic are present in DB. If you want to check for any of these then use || (OR operator)in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed the quotes in your query:

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE num = \"$number\" AND cnic = \"$cnic\"";
```

Since the fields are probably textual (varchar or something like that) you need to tell where the limits of the values you're comparing to are.

Also if you need to skip the saving if any of the values matches you should use OR:

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE num = \"$number\" OR cnic = \"$cnic\"";
```

Comment: Still not working. it's not showing any warning it simply saves the data.

Comment: its like its not passing through the if statements. Something is wrong there. I'm messing with it 2 days ago.

Comment: Maybe the more than one match is found. Try if (mysql_num_rows($cresult) > 0)

Comment: you might wanna select count(*) and see what the query returns instead of extracting all matching rows with all the columns and comparing the result count in php

Answer (score 0):

Try to add single quotes around your parameters and rewrite the query like this..

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `num` = '$number' OR cnic='$cnic'";
```

Also, on your **`if`** statement.. check like this

```
if (mysql_num_rows($cresult)>0) {
```

Also, stop using **`mysql_*`** functions as they are deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO instead.